# Adding controls to a Property Sheet at runtime (without Dialog Templates)

Tags: winapi, controls, runtime, addition, propertysheet

As far as I can see, the way you normally create Property Sheets in Win32 (I am using the API, not MFC) programming is you have a bunch of dialog templates for each tab page, and you make the property sheet out of them. I have read about creating Dialog Templates 'in memory' but I would prefer not to do it this way. How do you add controls to a Property Sheet programatically at runtime, just like you can create a `BUTTON` and add it to a Window at runtime?

Comment: Have you tried doing it "just like you can create a `BUTTON` and add it to a Window at runtime"?

Comment: @David Please tell me how I can do that! "just like you can create a BUTTON and add it to a Window at runtime" requires an HWND to add the BUTTON to, and I am not aware of a way to get the HWND of a page of a Property Sheet. If you could elaborate on that comment, it would be the answer.

Comment: Actually to clarify, I know how to get the HWND of an already existing Property Sheet page, but I don't know how to add one in the first place without a Dialog Template, even though a blank one is all I need.

Comment: @James Why can't you create a blank template and link that to your app? You can then create the property sheet with CreatePropertySheetPage and then add and remove controls to that property sheet as you please

Comment: @James if you absolutely have to use a template built on the fly in memory, and you can't bring yourself to link a resource to your app, then you need the DLGTEMPLATE structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645394%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: If you'll compile your comments and put it in an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @James I've added an answer based on my comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create a blank template and link that to your app. You can then create the property sheet with [CreatePropertySheetPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760807%28VS.85%29.aspx) and then add and remove controls to that property sheet as you please.

If you absolutely have to use a template built on the fly in memory, and you can't bring yourself to link a resource to your app, then you need the [DLGTEMPLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645394%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure.